# Python click: Make some options hidden

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm using `click` to build a CLI in Python. I have several options to the command I'm defining, and I want some of them to be hidden in `--help`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can. Use

```
@click.option(..., hidden=True)
```

The feature is now (March 2019) in the stable release of Click.

*Please note:* In [the first implementation](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/pull/500) the functionality was realised with a parameter `show=False`, but is now done  with `hidden=True`.

Comment: For info, you can also do the same on commands: `@click.command(..., hidden=true)`

Comment: Documentation link: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=hidden#click.Option

Comment: NB. This also works in Typer, which is based on Click.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is on the verge of being included in click, you can follow the development here:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/pull/500

Comment: The pull request still isn't available as of 2016-11-11, but according to comments should be in the 7.x version when that comes out.